# Add Annotation to MKMapView from outside the UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to display map markers from a API to my MKMapView. I'm coding inside Xamarin Studio for iOS. I'm calling the function `getAllMarkers();` that I've created.

Which looks like this:

```
private void getAllMarkers()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://example.com/");
    var request = new RestRequest(String.Format(""));

    client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
           JsonValue data = JsonValue.Parse(response.Content);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++){
        var store = new BasicMapAnnotation (new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.00, -1.00), "Shop name", "Extras);
        map.AddAnnotation(store);
     }
   });
}
```

This gives me the following error:
[image]

How can I add markers to the map from my function getAllMarkers()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [InvokeOnMainThread](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/)()

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    // manipulate UI controls
 `  map.AddAnnotation(store);`
});
```